# Creating a fresh, re-indexed array from a source array without using foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've created a import script to convert a spreadsheet containing vehicle makes and models into related database entities. My source array from the spreadsheet looks like this (each is a spreadsheet row):

```
$rows = [
    ['Brand A', 'Model A'],
    ['Brand A', 'Model A'],
    ['Brand A', 'Model B'],
    ['Brand A', 'Model B'],
    ['Brand A', 'Model B'],
    ['Brand A', 'Model C'],
    ['Brand B', 'Model A'],
    ['Brand B', 'Model B'],
    ['Brand B', 'Model B'],
    ['Brand B', 'Model B'],
    ['Brand B', 'Model C'],
    ['Brand B', 'Model C'],
];
```

I want this data in this format:

```
$data = [
    'Brand A' => [
        'Model A',
        'Model A',
        'Model B',
        'Model B',
        'Model B',
        'Model C',
    ],
    'Brand B' => [
        'Model A',
        'Model B',
        'Model B',
        'Model B',
        'Model C',
        'Model C',
    ],
];
```

I have a working example using a foreach loop:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $data[strval($row[0])][] => strval($row[1]);
}
```

I'd like to use one of the PHP `array` functions if possible. I've tried the following but it's not creating the brand name indexes:

```
$data = array_map(function ($row) {
    return $data[strval($row[0])][] = strval($row[1]);
}, $rows);
```

The array ends up as follows:

```
$data = [
    'Model A',
    'Model A',
    ...
];
```

Is this possible or am I wasting my time/over engineering this?

---

PT 2: Bonus points for making the models unique for a brand at the same time.

```
$data = [
    'Brand A' => [
        'Model A',
        'Model B',
        'Model C',
    ],
    'Brand B' => [
        'Model A',
        'Model B',
        'Model C',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

one way would be to use array_reduce like this

```
$data = array_reduce($rows, function ($acc, $row) {
    $acc[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
    return $acc;
}, []);
```

to make the subarrays unique you can use a combination of array_map and array_unique afterwards

```
$data = array_map(function ($subarr) {
    return array_unique($subarr);
}, $data);
```

Comment: +1 because your solution answer the question without a loop as per requested. But I would not use this solution, it is quite too much complicated.Nearly obsfucation here :-)

Comment: Nice! Thanks Stephan

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think this is over engineering things.

However, I'm going for the bonus point here!

```
$new = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $new[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
    $new[$row[0]] = array_unique($new[$row[0]]);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't meet the "no loops" criteria. Nice answer, though.

Comment: Yes I know. :-P The guys answer below does, but as you can see it is MORE code and harder to tell what is going on, which is why I wouldn't do it that way unless it was faster over a million iteration benchmark

Comment: It does read harder but the problem with loops for me is they end up everywhere in controllers, listeners - even in other loops. So I'll put these iterators into smaller classes and methods, slap some tests on them and they're golden.

Comment: You shouldn't have any logic in a controller action. a controllers job is to get data from the request and pass it to a service, get the result, and pass it to a view, and handle any expected exceptions, that's it. Sticking your methods in a separate class is the right thing to do, but make a service class, and call that from the controller so your actions are super tidy and the business logic isn't mixed with framework code

Comment: also, loops within loops is a sure sign that your method needs split up!

Comment: @delboy1978uk exactly. These are going into an import service to be used in a symfony sonata admin class. Debatable, but I think logic in extended vendor classes is worse than in controllers. At least with a controller you are in control (even though it's terrible). If the vendor adds a protected/public method that causes a collision, or just changes something that some of your extended functionality uses you're either stuck at a version or facing a potentially non-trivial refactor.

Comment: I try not to extend them and instead inject them in the constructor

Comment: Sadly, with the sonata admin you need to create a class for each entity you want to administrate. Luckily, they're small, mostly config and can just take a service.